# Can't find git repository on an enterprise github with token access?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I just started at a new company. This company has an enterprise github site at github.COMPANY.com. I'm on a Windows 10 box, logged into CentOS 7 server through putty, trying to start up a new branch of an existing repository.

They use token access to github (I have no prior experience), and I was able to setup my token, clone the necessary repository, make a test document, and commit it. But when I try to push back to the repo:

```
$ git push

remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://x-access-token:TOKENNUMBER@github.COMPANY.com/innovation/REPO_NAME.git/' not found
```

The address in quotes is the same exact text as I used to clone the repository

```
$ git clone htpps://x-access-token:TOKENNUMBER@github.COMPANY.com/innovation/REPO_NAME.git/
```

So I know the address is valid since I successfully cloned. It appears that I can pull just fine, although there is nothing to pull right now.

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Anyone have any ideas about the error message? I was actually thinking that my user might not have permissions to push, which is causing the 'not found' error since my token is not recognized as valid.